# get tag names and first child data with Jquery 

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to retrieve data from the child data of a tag from my ajax script. this works with javascript

```
coursename = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("sitelist");
name = coursename[3].firstChild.data
```

Can somebody help me with performing this using jQuery please? I thought this would work but it doesn't.

```
name = $("coursename", xml).text()
```

Any help or pointers would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('sitelist:eq(2)')
```

is the jQuery selector for that. You might want to use jQuerys `.data()` method as well to store something to that node.

Comment: Woudln't it be `eq(3)`, since it's `coursename[3]` in the original?

Answer (score 1):

```
name = $("sitelist", xmlDocument).eq(3).children(":first").text();
```

The [above](http://jsfiddle.net/F2yFs/) uses:

- **[jQuery context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)** to choose all `sitelist` tags within `xmlDocument`
- **[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to reduce the set of `sitelist`s to only the 4th one (index of 3)
- **[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)** to find all the direct children of the 4th `sitelist`
- **[`:first selector`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** to only pick the first child.
- **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** to retrieve the text in that node